# Appstore is opening Xcode's older version than installed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode6, mac-app-store

I recently updated Xcode 6.3.1 to Xcode 6.4.
Updates went well and I installed it successfully.

**Problem:** When I open it after installation, it was the same version as before. Xcode 6.3.1

*P.S:* Image is attached. Appstore is showing that xcode is updated to 6.4 version

[image]

Comment: Is there a new icon for Xcode 6.4 in launchpad?

Comment: It is showing only one icon for Xcode, I don't know if there is a new icon for Xcode 6.4 but it looks same as old to me.

Comment: @Muhammad There is only one version Xcode 6.3.1 in the location tab.

Comment: Same here, AppStore version 7.2, but keeps opening 7.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it Might be the bug in xcode 6.4 update .... Try to install again the 6.4 after uninstalling the older version.

Comment: This solved my problem, even though I knew that this could be the only solution. Thanks anyway!
+1 for simplicity.